# How to write the data into a csv file?

Tags: php, magento

Eg:the `csv` have two columns. The structure is : it only have the header.

```
sku name
```

Now, there is a foreach loop:

```
foreach ($collection as $product_all) 
{
    $sku = $product_all['sku'];
    $product_id = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($sku);
    $product    = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $product ->load($product_id);
    $name = $product['name'];
}
```

I want to put the `$sku` and the `$name` into the csv file, if there is 8000 rows lines. How do I do? I using the following code. But it doesn't work. How to correct it? Thank you.

```
foreach ($collection as $product_all) 
{
    $sku = $product_all['sku'];
    $product_id = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($sku);
    $product    = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $product ->load($product_id);   
    $name = $product['name'];
    $newCsvData = array();
    if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) 
    {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
        {
            $data[0] = $sku;
            $data[2] = $name;
            $newCsvData[] = $data;
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }

    $handle = fopen('test.csv', 'w');
    foreach ($newCsvData as $line) 
    {
        fputcsv($handle, $line);
    }

    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" isn't a good enough description of the problem. Please explain what about it doesn't work. Do you get error message? Does it create a CSV file at all? If so, in what way is it different to what you expect? ....... ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did not try it, but it should work.

```
$csvData = array();
foreach ($collection as $product_all) {
  $sku = $product_all['sku'];
  $product_id = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($sku);
  $product    = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
  $product ->load($product_id);   
  $name = $product['name'];

  $csvData[] = array($sku, $name);
}


$handle = fopen('test.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($handle, array('sku', 'name'));
foreach($csvData as $row) {
  fputcsv($handle, $row);
}
fclose($handle);
```

The `fputcsv` function takes care of all escaping for you, which is no small job if you want your csv file to work across any input.

After reading some comments on other answers, you could move the `fputcsv` call in the loop:

```
$handle = fopen('test.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($handle, array('sku', 'name'));

foreach ($collection as $product_all) {
  $sku = $product_all['sku'];
  $product_id = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($sku);
  $product    = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
  $product ->load($product_id);   
  $name = $product['name'];

  fputcsv($handle, array($sku, $name));
}

fclose($handle);
```

Comment: i am sorry,when i run over the code. there is no any data into the csv file.

Comment: Have you checked to see if `$collection` is not by any chance empty?

Comment: @stack2013110 Do you at least have the header?

Comment: yes, the $collection have all the data. when i test this $handle = fopen('test.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($handle, array('sku', 'name'));

foreach ($collection as $product_all) {  it still nothing in the csv except the header

Comment: yes, the test.csv header is written by me before i put it into the file.

Comment: @stack2013110 Try replacing `fputcsv($handle, array($sku, $name));` in the loop by `fputcsv($handle, array('sku', 'name'));`. That should output a header line for each entry and validate you go through the loop.

Comment: I just checked and even with arrays of empty strings or `null` values, `fputcsv` outputs lines to the file, so you should see the lines if you go through your loop.

Comment: if your using fputcsv($handle, array('sku', 'name')) in the loop,how do you write the sku and name into the test.csv

Comment: @stack2013110 This is just for a test, to make sure you go through the loop.

Comment: i  using fputcsv($handle, array('sku', 'name')) in the loop.there is still no any content in the test.csv except the first line. sku name

Comment: when i echo $sku; echo $name; in the loop,those are all have content output.

Comment: oh damn it, the test.csv chmode is not 777.

Comment: it's ok now, but i don't why in the csv there are 7097 lines. but when i open it using notepadd. it shows 7111 lines. why?

Comment: @stack2013110 Glad to hear it works. If you have new lines in some names, that might add to the number of lines? How do you get the 7097 line count?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution I can think of:

```
// The filename to write to
$csvFile = 'theCSVfile.csv';
$csvRows = array();

foreach ($collection as $product_all) {
  $sku = $product_all['sku'];
  $product_id = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($sku);
  $product    = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
  $product ->load($product_id);
  // Replacing quotation marks with CSV escaped ones
  $name = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $product['name'] );

  $csvRows[] = "{$sku},\"{$name}\"";
}

file_put_contents( $csvFile , implode( "\n" , $csvRows ) );
```

Bear in mind that this may produce invalid CSV syntax if the `$name` variable contains commas or other unusual characters.

As noted by **Bogdan**, this may be memory intensive, as it involves holding all of the rows in RAM before performing a single write to the file. If that is a concern, or you are dealing with a very large number of rows, the following code batches the writes into smaller chunks.

```
// The filename to write to
$csvFile = 'theCSVfile.csv';
// Rows per chunk
$csvChunk = 1000;

// Initialise the Array
$csvRows = array();
// Variable to check if first write performed
$firstWriteDone = false;

function writeChunk(){
  global $csvFile, $csvRows, $csvChunk, $firstWriteDone;

  if( count( $csvRows )==$csvChunk ){
    // Chunk Limit Reached - Write to disk
    file_put_contents(
      $csvFile ,
      ( !$firstWriteDone ? "\n" : '' ) . implode( "\n" , $csvRows ) ,
      ( !$firstWriteDone ? FILE_APPEND : 0 )
    );
    // Set the First Write Done flag
    $firstWriteDone = true;
    // Reset the Array
    $csvRows = array();
  }
}

foreach ($collection as $product_all) {
  $sku = $product_all['sku'];
  $product_id = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($sku);
  $product    = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
  $product ->load($product_id);
  // Replacing quotation marks with CSV escaped ones
  $name = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $product['name'] );

  $csvRows[] = "{$sku},\"{$name}\"";

  if( count( $csvRows )==$csvChunk ){
    // Chunk Limit Reached - Write to disk
    writeChunk();
  }
}
if( count( $csvRows ) ){
  // Write the Last Chunk, even if not at the limit
  writeChunk();
}
```

Comment: thank you, the $name will be contain  commas or other unusual characters. is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: You could wrap the $name in htmlentities()

Comment: when i run  the code it shows Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in

Comment: If you data set has 8000 rows it can eat up a lot of memory fast. Instead of caching all the csv rows data into an array, try writing it to the file as you are iterating over the collection in the first foreach `foreach ($collection as $product_all)`

Comment: I've posted a simple answer based on my above comment

Comment: @stack2013110: I have updated the code to allow for some unusual characters in the `$name` variable.
@Bogdan: I have also posted a variant where rows are written in blocks of 1,000 which should reduce the memory overheads.

Answer (score 0):

your code is messed up man ...
for each DB entry .. you Read the csv .. collect the date from it (none ?)
and "write" it to the csv ..

fixing your code:

```
    $newCsvData = array();

    foreach ($collection as $product_all) { 
        $sku = $product_all['sku'];

        $product_id = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($sku);

        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

        $product->load($product_id);

        $name = $product['name'];

        //move BEFORE the foreach
        /*$newCsvData = array();*/

        //remove this ...
        /*if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                $data[0] = $sku;
                $data[2] = $name;
                $newCsvData[] = $data;
            }
            fclose($handle);
        }*/

        //move AFTER the foreach
        /*
        $handle = fopen('test.csv', 'w');

        foreach ($newCsvData as $line) {
            fputcsv($handle, $line);
        }

        fclose($handle);*/
    }

    $handle = fopen('test.csv', 'w');

    foreach ($newCsvData as $line) {
        fputcsv($handle, $line);
    }

    fclose($handle);
```

Check the other examples they are probably better, just wonted to point out what is wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Write the rows to the file as you are iterating over the products collection.

```
$fh = fopen('test.csv', 'w');

foreach ($collection as $product_all) {
    $sku = $product_all['sku'];
    $product_id = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($sku);
    $product    = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $product ->load($product_id);   
    $name = $product['name'];

    fwrite($fh, "{$sku},{$name}\n");
}

fclose($fh);
```